# Writing to a spreadsheet in Game maker studio 2.0

Tags: gml, game-maker-studio-2

I'm making a short game for one of my classes, its for a small research study, so i want to be able to write the participants game data to a new line in a spreadsheet. I've seen stuff on reading from a .csv file but nothing about writing to it and was wondering what i need to do for that.

Answer (score 0):

CSV, as per the name, is a very simple format - items go one per line and are separated by commas. If the item contains a comma or is multi-line, it should be surrounded by double-quotes `"`. If the item also needs to contain double quotes, they are replaced by pairs of double quotes `""`.

```
name,value
ex1,hello
ex2,"hello, you!"
ex3,"hello, ""quotes""!"
ex4,"hello,
lines!"
```

Rest assured, this is not hard to produce with `file_text_*` or buffer functions. You can check [this implementation](https://github.com/JujuAdams/SNAP/blob/master/scripts/snap_to_csv/snap_to_csv.gml) for an example.